# MAX IF in Excel with the same range of data

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with a lot of voltage numbers and I want to get the maximum and minimum deviations from a value (the value is 0.95).

The ideal formula would be:

```
=MAX(IF([range of many values]<0.95,[range of many values],""))
```

The range is a matrix of values, if that matters.

But this doesn't work since IF doesn't like ranges.
Is there a way to do this without creating another sheet just for the IF values results?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formula

```
=MAX([range of many values]*([range of many values]<0.95))
```

as an array formula, i.e. hold hold `ctrl-shift` when pressing enter after typing the formula.

By entering this as an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7), the intermediate computations can return arrays.  So, `]*([range of many values]<0.95)` will return an array that has `1` for `True`, and `0` for `False`.  This is then multiplied by the original values in the array, entry by entry, and returns an array, which will feed into the `MAX` function.

BTW, your original formula will also work, if it is entered as an array formula.

Answer (score 1):

There are also ways you could do this with non array formulas, e.g.

`=SMALL(Range,COUNTIF(Range,"<0.95"))`

That works because if there are 100 values in your range and 30 are < 0.95 then the value you want is the 30th smallest value in the range